# Olympiad Mathematical Kosovo 2012 (Problem grade 9)

Tags: contest-math

Let $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\ldots,a_{2011},a_{2012}$ be integers. Exactly 29 of them are divisible by 3. Show that $a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2+a_{3}^2+\ldots+a_{2011}^2+a_{2012}^2$ is also divisible by 3.

Comment: If $n$ is not divisible by $3$, then what is $n^2\pmod 3$?

Comment: $2012-29$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I found that, too.  I think the point is to show that the sum of squares of any 3 numbers, each of which are not divisible by 3, is divisible by 3.

Comment: Observe (this is the remark of Thomas Andrews) that if $a$ is not divisible by $3$, then the remainder when you divide $a^2$ by $3$ is $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: of course!  QED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *very easy* to solve once you know congruences, and harder when you are young and do not. That is to say a "tricky", though nice, kind of problem.

There are 2012 - 29 = 1983 squares that are all 1 mod 3, since squares can only be 0 or 1 mod 3 (if a = 2 mod 3 then a^2 = 4 mod 3 = 1 mod 3) and we have excluded all those who were divisible by 3. Their sum will be equal to 1983 mod 3 = 0 mod 3, and so divisible by 3 since 1983 is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\, $ mod prime $p:\ a\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a^{p-1}\!\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,a_1^{p-1}\! +\cdots+ a_n^{p-1}\! \equiv\:$the number of $a_i\! \not\equiv 0$